# How to implement this else if line?

Tags: excel, vba

I can't figure out for the life of me where to put this Else or Else If statement in this IF statement block. Quick rundown: if I find the value I type in my input box within the designated rows, populate select data from that row in the sheet I designate. The other if statement after that relies on another value (to further filter the results).

It works great, but I just want a msg box populated if the job code I put in exists, but not based on the second IF statement value. Right now it just doesn't populate data, but that may give the illusion something is broken rather than it didn't meet all criteria.

I want to add something like `Else if .... msg box "Job code exists, but not under this EC member` in between the second indented if statement (after the Do/while loop) here:

```
    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address

        Do
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then
                sh.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 5).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 8) = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 9) = rFound.Offset(, 7).Value

                rw = rw + 1

            End If
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

    Else
        MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not eligible.", , "Error"
    End If
```

whole code:

```
Sub tgr()

Dim rFound As Range
Dim lJobCode As String
Dim lLob As String
Dim sFirst As String
Dim sResults As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Long

lJobCode = Application.InputBox("Please provide a job code", "Job Code", Type:=2)
lLob = Application.InputBox("Please select EC Member", "EC Member", Type:=2)
If lJobCode = "False" Or lLob = "False" Then Exit Sub   'Pressed cancel

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
rw = 8
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
    Set rFound = .Find(lJobCode, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address

        Do
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then
                sh.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 5).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 8) = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 9) = rFound.Offset(, 7).Value

                rw = rw + 1

            End If
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

    Else
        MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not eligible.", , "Error"
    End If

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How about adding `Else msgbox("job code exists but not under this ec member")` after `rw = rw + 1 `?

Comment: @shahkalpesh I tried that before, but displays the msgbox every loop through. Say I have 5 rows, and the job code I type in the first input satisfies the if statement, but the second input value doesn't exist, it will populate the msg box for every one of the five loops before exiting and displaying no data. I want it to loop through all times before displaying the message ("job code exists but not under this ec member")

Comment: @shahkalpesh Im thinking it needs to go after the `loop while rFound...` and before the `Else job code not eligible...` statement below

Comment: I have added an answer and you may have to build up on it. I am using a variable that counts if it find 1 lob. If it does not find a single lob, it will show the dialog. If the answer helps you, you can mark it "accepted".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to introduce a flag to capture a state meaning "Found lJobCode, but no match for lJob", then set that flag to `True` when the inner condition is met, and after you've gone through all search results, pop a `MsgBox` if the flag is still `False`.

```
Dim matched As Boolean
If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
    sFirst = rFound.Address

    Do
        If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then
            matched = True
            '...
        End If
    Loop While ...

    If Not matched Then MsgBox "Your new message here"

 Else
    MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not eligible.", , "Error"
 End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! Shahkalpesh's answer works too, can I grant both answers correct?

Comment: @nicklanta hi, I'm Mat - Shahkalpesh's solution is very similar, but will blow up if there are more than 32,767 search results (because they're declaring the counter `As Integer` rather than `As Long`) -- you don't really need to count anything, just a `Boolean` flag is enough.

Comment: Agree. I dont know how many instances does the sheet have. The integer can be changed to long, if that is the case.

Comment: @shahkalpesh If I change the integer to long, will this satisfy any scenario that Boolean may have hiccups?

Comment: @nicklanta if the count is meaningful, keep it; if the only meaningful information is whether the count is 0 or not, I'd go with a Boolean.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Correct, It's either the value typed/cell selected exists in column 5 of the raw data, or it doesn't. Will Boolean satisfy this?

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I know it should because its either true/false, I wasn't sure what shahkalpesh was mentioning with instances where it's Boolean might not work?

Comment: @nicklanta you can make the counter a `Long` (there's no need to use the 16-bit `Integer` type in VBA anymore anyway) if you need the actual count, or use a `Boolean` flag if you don't. There's not much more to it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Columns("A")
    Set rFound = .Find(lJobCode, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
        sFirst = rFound.Address

        dim lobFoundCount as integer
        lobFoundCount = 0

        Do
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(rFound.Row, 5).Value = lLob Then
                lobFoundCount = lobFoundCount + 1

                sh.Cells(rw, 4) = rFound.Offset(, 0).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 5) = rFound.Offset(, 1).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 6) = rFound.Offset(, 3).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 7) = rFound.Offset(, 5).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 8) = rFound.Offset(, 6).Value
                sh.Cells(rw, 9) = rFound.Offset(, 7).Value

                rw = rw + 1
            End If
            Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)

        Loop While rFound.Address <> sFirst

        If lobFoundCount = 0 Then 'No rows have matching lob
            Msgbox("job code exists but not under this ec member")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Job Code [" & lJobCode & "] not eligible.", , "Error"
    End If

End With
```